# React native life cycle method to re-render component

Tags: react-native, react-native-image, react-navigation-stack

In react native application ImageCarousel used to display array of images and it worked fine. Later I introduced the createMaterialBottomTabNavigator to navigate, navigation is working fine but after the BottomTabNavigator library is used for navigation, the  screen initially loads without displaying the images but when screen orientation changes it start displaying images.
I am new  to react-native and please guide me to solve this.

libraries used :

```
import ImageCarousel from 'react-native-image-page';

import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
```

Comment: Please add an issue reproducing snack

Comment: I have not reported this as a issue for either.